# CSS - Align div elements in three columns

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align a list of labels, input radios and icons. The alignment should be:

```
   Label     Icon
() LongLabel Icon
() Label     Icon
```

Here my code:

```css
div.mygrid {
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: max-content max-content;
    grid-gap:5px;
}
div.mygrid > div > label       { text-align:left; }
```

```html
<div class="mygrid">
  <div>
    <label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Long Text #1</label>
    <i>Colum2</i>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label><input type="radio">Label #2</label>
    <i>Colum2</i>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label><input type="radio">Label #3</label>
    <i>Colum2</i>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Also I find awful to define spaces to replace the space of the radiobutton:

```
<label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Long Text #1</label>
```

Any idea how can I achieve that?

Comment: This would be much easier with CSS grid if you reduce the unnecessary nesting  (demo: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vpdjn7gw/) of elements, also your first `<label>` element contains, and refers to, no associated form control, which is the only purpose for the `<label>` element. If it has - and refers to - no control then it has no reason to be a `<label>`

Comment: I am using angular ngFor and ngFor adds this unnecessary div...

Comment: Is there no way of modifying, or preventing, that?

Comment: Yes, using ng-container. I will try it as soon as possible

Answer (score 2):

If you don't insist on using Grid, I propose a solution similar to the following (should be self-explanatory). Adjust values (`width` and `padding`) as needed.

```css
label {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 160px;
}
label.L1 {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  width: 30px;
  margin: 0;
}
i {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mygrid">
  <div>
    <label class="L1">Long Text #1</label>
    <i>Colum2</i>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio"><label>Label #2</label>
    <i>Colum2</i>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio"><label>Label #3</label>
    <i>Colum2</i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div.mygrid {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
div.mygrid > div > label       { text-align:left; }

.ml-3 {
margin-left: 17px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mygrid">
  <div class="ml-3">
    <label>Long Text #1</label>
    <i>Colum2</i>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label><input type="radio">Label #2</label>
    <i>Colum2</i>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label><input type="radio">Label #3</label>
    <i>Colum2</i>
  </div>  
</div>
```